# Graphene: "Expected a value of type XXX but received: ..."

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm using `graphene-django` to build my API. I have a DjangoObjectType named `StoreType` which represents the model Store. This model has a MultiSelectField named `opening_days` that indicates what days in the week the store is open. To create new stores, I use this mutation:

```
class Weekdays(graphene.Enum):
    MO = "Mo"
    TU = "Tu"
    WE = "We"
    TH = "Th"
    FR = "Fr"
    SA = "Sa"
    SU = "Su"

class CreateStore(graphene.Mutation):
    store = graphene.Field(StoreType)

    class Arguments:
        opening_days = graphene.Argument(graphene.List(Weekdays))

    def mutate(self, info, opening_days):
        store = Store(opening_days=opening_days)
        store.save()
        return CreateStore(store=store)
```

The mutation works perfectly. But then, when I try to query a store, I get the error `"Expected a value of type \"StoreOpeningDays\" but received: Monday, Tuesday",` which makes sense really, because this field saves the data as a single string with the values separated by commas. The issue is that graphene is expecting the list specified in `graphene.List(Weekdays)` which is impossible to retrieve.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the code for the Django model and also for `StoreType`? If the data is being stored in the db as expected you should just need to create a custom resolver for the `opening_days` field on `StoreType` to return the correct type.

Comment: Please share the Store model

Answer (score -1):

You have a line that reads:

```
return CreateStore(store=store)
```

The lowercase of the *store* variable on both sides of the = leads me to believe that either the outbound or inbound information points to itself.

Though not familiar with `graphene-django`...

- check the scope of the *store* variable. If the left side is meant to reference the parameter name from the CreateStore function, then trying renaming the right side to ensure that they are not conflicting.
- Does the CreateStore parameter need to be prefixed with a special character so the program knows it is directly referencing the parameter name as defined in the CreateStore function?  Just like an SQL command parameter in C#:

  ```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myparmname", mylocalval);
  ```